# Extract numerical value from string

Tags: grep

I want to extract the numerical value out of the below command output :

```
bash-3.2# psrinfo -pv | head -1
The physical processor has 1 virtual processor (0)
```

That is, the output should be "1".

Can someone provide me any commands or a small script to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cut`-command to do what you need.

```
$ psrinfo -pv | head -1 | cut -f 5 -d ' '
1
```

`-f 5` means the 5-th field, and `-d ' '` means use space as field delimiter.